# Area bounded by $x^2+ y^2 \le 9 \pi^{2}$ and $\sin(x-y)\geq0$.

Tags: calculus

Find the area bounded by the curve $x^2 + y^2 \le 9 \pi^{2}$ and curve $\sin(x-y)\geq 0$.

My approach
Though the answer is $\frac{9\pi^{3}}{2}$ which is half the area of circle and i got the answer by plotting $2n\pi \le (x-y) \le 2n\pi+\pi$ but I could not satisfy myself as Sine angle corresponds to the following rule $n\pi+(-1)^{n}\alpha$

Comment: The region $\{(x,y):\sin(x-y)\geq 0\}$ **is not** a *curve*, neither it is $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 9\pi^2\}$.

Comment: I know it is a straight line but questioner has put it as curve to confuse everyone as both y=Sin x and x=Sin y are curves but Sin(x-y)=c is a straight line where c$\in$ [-1,1]

Comment: It's not a straight line either.  Jack is referring to the ≥ sign.

Comment: $x^2+y^2\leq9\pi^{2}$ is a circle of radius $3\pi$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your region is exactly the one colored in blue in the picture below. As the radius of the circle is $3\pi$ we have $\sin(x-y)\geq 0$ for

$0\leq x-y\leq \pi$ that is $x\leq y\leq x+\pi$

the strip between the lines $y=x$ and $y=x+\pi$

then $x+2\pi\leq y \leq x+3\pi$

and $x-2\pi\leq y \leq x-\pi$

and so on. The region is the part internal of the circle intersection the stripes we were talking above.

As we can see the parts in blue and the parts in white cover the same area so the region has area half of the circle.

Hope this helps

$$...$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The map $(x, y) \mapsto (-x, -y)$ preserves areas, maps the set $x^2 + y^2 \leq 9$ to itself, and precisely interchanges the areas $\sin (x-y) > 0$ and $\sin (x-y) < 0$. (The region defined by $\sin (x-y) = 0$, which has measure zero, is of no account.) So exactly half of the circle $x^2 + y^2 < 9$ satisfies $\sin (x-y) > 0$.